# Keras model input samples and labels have different dimensions error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, softmax

I am trying to create a model to predict stock prices.

I am getting an error saying the input shapes of the samples (1,1,20) and labels (1,1,3) have different shapes.

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 20 for '{{node categorical_hinge/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](categorical_hinge/Cast, financial_model/dense_2/Softmax)' with input shapes: [1,1,3], [1,1,20].

I have 20 features and the labels are one hot encoded in the form of: [higher price, lower price, same price].

Do I need to pad the labels data with 0s in order to match the dimensions of the samples data?

My model is as follows:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]))
hidden = keras.layers.LSTM(x_train.shape[2], activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)(inputs)
dropout = keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(hidden)
output = keras.layers.Dense(dense_units, activation='softmax')(dropout)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output, name="financial_model")

model.compile(
loss=keras.losses.CategoricalHinge(),
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
metrics=["accuracy"],
)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data= 
(x_test,y_test))
```

thanks

Comment: What is the value of dense_units?

Comment: It was 20, I changed it to 3 but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: You may need to provide some more code snippets to reproduce the error like sample dataset and data preprocessing part.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71661321/valueerror-dimensions-must-be-equal-but-are-2-and-64-for-node-binary-crosse) similar issue of same error which may help you to solve this issue.