# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 64 for '{{node binary_crossentropy/mul}} with input shapes[?,2], [?,64]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying binary classification of text with bi-lstm model but getting this error: ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 64 for '{{node binary_crossentropy/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](binary_crossentropy/Cast, binary_crossentropy/Log)' with input shapes: [?,2], [?,64].
I am a beginner please provide some valuable solutions.

```
text=df['text']
label=df['label']

X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=max_len,padding=pad_type,truncating=trunc_type)
Y = pd.get_dummies(label).values    
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 0.20)
print(X_train.shape,Y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape,Y_test.shape)

#model creation
model=tf.keras.Sequential([
 # add an embedding layer
 tf.keras.layers.Embedding(word_count, 16, input_length=max_len),
 tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
 # add another bi-lstm layer
 tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(2,return_sequences=True)),
 # add a dense layer
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax),
 # add the prediction layer
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid),
])
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(X_train,  Y_train, validation_data=(X_test,  Y_test), epochs = 10, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks = [callback_func], verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output dimension of the prediction layer of the binary classification should be 2:

```py
# add the prediction layer
tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)
```

Flatten:

```py
#model creation
model=tf.keras.Sequential([
 # add an embedding layer
 tf.keras.layers.Embedding(word_count, 16, input_length=max_len),
 tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
 # add another bi-lstm layer
 tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(2,return_sequences=True)),
 # add flatten
 tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),  #<========================
 # add a dense layer
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax),
 # add the prediction layer
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid),
])
```

Comment: after adding 2 dimension I got this error:  ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 64, 2) vs (None, 2)).

Comment: Can you provide the result of the following two lines of code?print(X_train.shape,Y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape,Y_test.shape)

Comment: (782220, 64) (782220, 2)
(195556, 64) (195556, 2)

Comment: You try to flatten before adding a dense layer, ie: model.add(Flatten()).

Comment: Thanks Alot..!!!! I have been struggling with this problem for days.. thank you sooo much...!

Comment: Just one comment. Be careful about last layer, with `tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)`, outptus will not sum 1. Just to consider if its what are you lookin for. If we want to do a two categories classification, we usually use Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')